# How to check replication snapshot agent status?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, merge-replication

I'd like to check the status of the agent after I start it using this statement

```
EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication
```

As I want to do a next step that needs the job to be already started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I got a work around way

```
SELECT snapshot_ready FROM sysmergepublications
```

This query returns 0 if not ready and 1 if started

Thanks all for your contribution :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a built-in replication stored procedure to check the snapshot agent status, I could be wrong.  However, you could query MSsnapshot_history.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    agent_id, 
    runstatus, 
    start_time, 
    time, 
    duration, 
    comments, 
    delivered_transactions,
    delivered_commands, 
    delivery_rate, 
    error_id, 
    timestamp 
FROM dbo.MSsnapshot_history
WHERE comments = 'Starting agent.'
```

Likewise, you can check when the snapshot agent is finished:

```
SELECT 
    agent_id, 
    runstatus, 
    start_time, 
    time, 
    duration, 
    comments, 
    delivered_transactions,
    delivered_commands, 
    delivery_rate, 
    error_id, 
    timestamp 
FROM dbo.MSsnapshot_history
WHERE comments = '[100%] A snapshot of 68 article(s) was generated.'
```

Alternatively, you could the status of the Snapshot Agent job using sp_help_job.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use while loop to check if agent is running or not before executing other scripts:

```
use [distribution];
declare @status int = 2

 select @status = status
 FROM dbo.MSReplication_monitordata
 WHERE publication = 'PublicationName' and agent_type = 1

 while @status = 3
 begin
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
 select @status = status
 FROM dbo.MSReplication_monitordata
 WHERE publication = 'Publication.Name' and agent_type = 1
 end
```

reference: [T-SQL script to wait till status of snap agent is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887640/t-sql-script-to-wait-till-status-of-snap-agent-is-completed/53913018#53913018)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older thread. However, as this could still very well be something that needs to be done in current versions of SQL (2017/2019 as of this update), here is a function I use in powershell.  Its purpose is to sit until snapshot is available before rebuilding replication in our DEV/QA environment.

```
# =======================================================================================================================================
# WAIT UNTIL SNAPSHOT CREATED
# =======================================================================================================================================
Function Wait-ForSnapshotCreation {
    [Cmdletbinding()]

    Param (
        [int] $InitialSleepInSec = 60
       ,[int] $IncrementalSleepInSec = 2
       ,[string] $ReplicationPublication
       ,[string] $ReplicationDistributor
    )

    Process {
        $SleepMessage = "Sleeping for {0} seconds at the start..." -f $InitialSleepInSec
        $TotalSleepInSec = $SleepInSec
        $MonitorSQL = "exec sp_replmonitorhelppublication @publication = N'$ReplicationPublication'"
        Write-Message -Message ($SleepMessage)
        Start-Sleep -s $InitialSleepInSec

        Do {
             $MonitorStatus = (Invoke-SQLCmd -Query ($MonitorSQL) -ServerInstance $ReplicationDistributor -Database 'Distribution' -AbortOnError)
             If ($MonitorStatus.status -eq 3) {
                 $SleepMessage = "Replication status is still 'running' (3).   Will sleep for {0} more seconds. Slept {1} seconds so far..." -f $IncrementalSleepInSec, $TotalSleepInSec
                 Write-Message -Message ($SleepMessage)

                 Start-Sleep -s $IncrementalSleepInSec
                 $TotalSleepInSec += $IncrementalSleepInSec

             } # If...

        } Until ($MonitorStatus.status -ne 3)

    } # Process

} # Function
```

The following is an example call (used just before creating subscribers) :

```
Wait-ForSnapshotCreation -InitialSleepInSec 15 -IncrementalSleepInSec 1 -ReplicationPublication '<YOUR_PUBLICATION>' -ReplicationDistributor '<YOUR_DISTRIBUTION_SERVER_INSTANCE>'
```

Answer (score -1):

Check its run status. Here are its values:
 1 = Start.

2 = Succeed.

3 = In progress.

4 = Idle.

5 = Retry.

6 = Fail.